# layout.cshtml and index.cshtml problems in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to asp.net web development. I'm creating a website using bootstrap.js for front-end styling. I have my layout.cshtml for the common things to appear and now in my index.cshtml which is the home page for my site, I'm not able to display the content. I want to create a login form in the homepage. Please review the code.

Comment: Where is the index.cshtml located?  What is the name of your default controller?

Comment: _Please review the code_? WHAT CODE?

Answer (score 0):

Try using layout to display the layout content in the view page (index) as below,

```
@{
    Layout = layoutname;
}
```